# Cava Packger executable (made from perl) not working in 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, perl, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, executable

I have prepared executable from my perl code for distribution
It works fine on my own ubuntu 12.04 where it was created
It should work without perl on any system
But After execution of executable on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, (64 bit) it gives
Error:

```
Can't load '/home/osboxes/Version-1/lib/vrt/16e8aba612e215bf6a5195289f1a16d8/Prima.so' for module Prima: libgif.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at <content>/DynaLoader.pm line 157.
```

After installing libgif4 it gave error

```
libtiff.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What may be the cause for this and solution for this.

Comment: Have you tried installing `libgif4` which it says in the error message it failed to load ?

Comment: after installing libgif4 It gave error about libtiff4 i installed it too and the problem is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS includes libtiff5 by default. Versions up to 13.04 had libtiff4. I made the executable compatible with libtiff4. also just installing libtiff4 by Ubuntu Software Center did not help so I installed it manually.
Downloaded it from [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tiff3/libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) and installed by command:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libtiff4_3.9.7-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```